# In basketball, can you score by bouncing the ball off the ground?

Tags: rules, basketball

If a player slams the ball on the ground so hard that it bounces into the hoop, is that a valid goal?

(Bonus trivia question: has this occurred in a professional or collegiate game?)

Comment: The second question is answered here: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1657/if-the-basketball-goes-through-bottom-of-rim-and-re-enters-is-it-a-basket

Comment: @studro Thanks. I've removed that portion of the question.